# What should be the image resolution for Nexus One or Droid?

Tags: android, screen, resolution, device

As Android supports multiple devices from different manufacturers
there are different screen resolutions supported.

The table that is available at
https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support
is not very clear to me.

It shows WVGA and FWVGA in MDPI for Large Screens and HDPI for Normal
screens. So, if the image is kept in drawable-mdpi and its resolution
is 320 * 480 then which image will be taken by Large Screens device of
MDPI.

Moreover, there are two screen resolutions for HDPI i.e. 480 * 800 and
480 * 854. So, with what screen resolution the image should be built.

I want to place the background image which looks distorted in WVGA
emulator since its resolution is 320 * 480.

I have read about nine patchable images but I think they are better
for button images and edittext images so that they can stretch
according to the data in it.

Can someone please guide me in this?

Comment: You haven't asked any questions, so we cannot readily guide you.

Comment: the question in this is where?

Comment: It shows WVGA and FWVGA in MDPI for Large Screens and HDPI for Normal screens. So, if the image is kept in drawable-mdpi and its resolution is 320 * 480 then which image will be taken by Large Screens device of MDPI?

Moreover, there are two screen resolutions for HDPI i.e. 480 * 800 and 480 * 854. So, with what screen resolution the image should be built? 

Sorry for not being very clear and specific about it.

Comment: welcome to the world of fragmentation... Some companies have make a killing (millions and millions of $$$) selling tool helping to alleviate the fragmentation issue. On correctly designed mobile apps you don't have "one resolution". You have "one codebase" that can automagically fetch the correct resources (like, say, a 320x480 picture or a 480x800) depending on the device. This is not trivial to do. Welcome to mobile application development ;) (been there, done that)

Answer (score 1):

It all depends on what you are trying to do. It appears you are most concerned with getting a picture in one mode to look good in another mode. Maybe read this section near the top of the page you referenced:

> At run time, the platform provides three types of support to your
>   application, to ensure the best possible display on the current device
>   screen:

Comment: Well, I understand there needs to different set of resources for different screens. But as the document in the above link suggests there are Large Screens for MDPI too which has a screen resolution of 480 * 800. How will the Large Screen device of MDPI get the resource from drawable-hdpi. Or do we need to make another folder for drawable-large? I hope that the question is clear to you all now.